# Python: Suggestions in reducing complexity

Tags: python, algorithm, function, loops

**Task:** Given a string, S, of length N that is indexed from 0 to N-1 , print its even-indexed and odd-indexed characters as 2 space-separated strings on a single line.

**Input Format**: The first line contains an integer, T (the number of test cases). 
Each line  i of the T subsequent lines contain a String S, .

**Constraints** : T in range(1,11), len of String S in range(2,10001).

```
T = int(input().strip())
if T in range(1,11):
    for i in range(T):
        S = str(input().strip())
        arr= []
        arr +=S
        #print(arr[1])
        eve = []
        odd = []
        if len(arr) in range(2,10001):
            for n in range(0,len(arr)):
                if n%2 ==0:
                    eve.append(arr[n])
                else:
                    odd.append(arr[n])
        eve1 = ''.join(eve)
        odd1 = ''.join(odd)
        print(eve1,odd1)
```

Answer (score 7):

You could simplify your code by using [advanced slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) on strings

```
s = input().strip()
print(s[::2], s[1::2])
```

For `s[i:j:k]`

`i` is the start index, if omitted, it just uses `0`

`j` is the end index, if omitted, it just uses `len(s)`

`k` is the step value, so it will iterate though the sequence by that amount.

So for even indexed characters, we start at the `0` index and step through every other character.  For odd indexed characters, we just start at the `1` index and get every other character.